# SVN - Merge history of two repos

Tags: svn

We migrated some code from one SVN repo to other without keeping the history.

Is it possible to merge the history of both old and new repos?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no overlap between the histories in the old repo and the new repo, you could merge them into a third repo.

1. svnadmin dump oldrepo > repo1.dump
2. svnadmin dump --incremental -r2:*MAXREV* newrepo > repo2.dump
3. svnadmin create thirdrepo
4. svnadmin load thirdrepo < repo1.dump
5. svnadmin load thirdrepo < repo2.dump

where *MAXREV* is the youngest revision in your new repo, and 2 represents the second revision in your new repo, assuming that the 1st revision was the import.  The incremental flag is necessary to avoid Subversion trying to "add" all the files again.

See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate