# Merge two SVN repositories with branches & tags

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I've got two SVN repositories which I want to merge into one, they both have multiple branches & tags which I'd like to maintain along with all the version history.

Repo 1 trunk HEAD is the same as Repo 2 trunk revision 2 and all the branches & tags for Repo 1 & Repo 2 are branched and already merged back into its own repository trunk.

As there is a common point for both repository trunks and all of the branches and tags are created and merged back within it's own repository (there are none that span both Repo 1 and 2) is it possible to merge them so they become one continuous repository so when I'm looking back through the history it's like they've always been one repository?

I've found other questions on here that are similar but from what I understand of them they are just merging the trunk of two repositories and not branches or tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN - Merge history of two repos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432981/svn-merge-history-of-two-repos)

Comment: I only just noticed the link here about a possible duplicate question of this. From what I remember when trying to do this before was running the commands separately, as answered in the other question, didn't work for me; I never worked out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encase anyone else comes across this problem I finally managed to find a solution that worked at [http://proger.i-forge.net/Merging_revisions_of_separate_SVN_repositories/ejf][1]

[1]: http://proger.i-forge.net/Merging_revisions_of_separate_SVN_repositories/ejf Make sure the revision you start the dumping from is after you've created & committed all the files & directories you currently have checked out as this caught me out a little.

Here's the command required:

```
svnadmin dump Latest/Repo -r 122:999 --incremental | svnadmin load Backup/Repo/Path
```

This is all one command, the | is part of the SVN command not to show that they are two separate commands. "Latest/Repo" is your new repository & "Backup/Repo/Path" is the old recovered repository, they both refer to the actual repositories not the checked out copies.

Hope this helps people.